# How to determine the number of accepted arguments in a lambda in ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

Is there any method or something `x` in which, provided `z = lambda {|x, y, z| nil}` we can say

```
z.x #=> 3
```

Of course, syntax can differ if it gets the job done. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
z.arity #=> 3
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Proc#arity`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html#M001554) method tells you this:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > f = lambda { |x,y,z| nil }
 => #<Proc:0x000001009ca830@(irb):1 (lambda)> 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > f.arity
 => 3
```